# Exported field collection field has null UUID

Tags: configuration, entities

In D8, I have a configuration management error. I have created a field named 'field_icon_link' of type “Field Collection”. I export my config. If I try to import this config I get a UUID error.

> Unexpected error during import with operation update for
>   field_collection.field_collection.field_icon_link: Attempt to save a
>   configuration entity ‘field_icon_link’ with UUID ‘’ when this entity
>   already exists with UUID ‘b18531e5-8e5a-4708-a0e2-7d7503a2e631’

I inspect the exported configuration file. The UUID is set to null, "uuid: null". Of course the field in the DB has a UUID, so its true, they don't match. I have re-exported a few times, the UUID for this field is always null. Other config files for other fields all have a UUID.

Any suggestions? Are there reasons a field may export with a null UUID or could this a bug for the Field Collection module?

Comment: I found someone else talking about this. They seem to think the issue is not Field Collection specific. https://www.drupal.org/node/2715997